# How do I learn this Peruvian technique?

Tags: technique, classical-guitar

I can't figure out how he is playing the part with the triplets beginning 1:18 :(
would love to learn this technique but how? Is he playing two notes at once, or just semiquavers like in Recuerdos de la Alhambra?

How do I learn the phrasing? Maybe somebody knows a resource that allows me to figure it out, e.g. a simpler example of this technique or a tutorial.

Comment: Tim's comment from your other post: "It's tremolo, played with probably two fingers, in semis. While the counter melody is played with the thumb on lower strings."

Comment: It is played with your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th fingers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I83lanJNze0

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment - melody played using thumb (p), tremolo played using index, middle and ring (i, m, a), on top string. There appears to be tune note followed by 3 semis, which have manifested themselves to you as triplets.

Comment: Yep - have just tried playing this various different ways and this is the only one that works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just tremolo played on the 2nd, 3rd and 4th fingers.

Comment: Isn't this what I wrote...  or do you mean middle, ring and pinky, which he doesn't use.

Answer (score -1):

From just a quick look and listen it seems to be a four (not triplets) 32nd note tremolo on the B (2nd) string using the pinky as well as i, m and a. The camera operator chose exactly the wrong time to change the focus.

Comment: The notes are too high to be played on the 2nd string. His fretting hand would have to be much higher up the fingerboard.